# CRM and iframe aspx page form submission

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, crm

***Scenario :***

I have `aspx` page which I need to `Iframe` on `CRM's` Opportunity form. This `aspx` page has form which submits data into the other database.

***Requirement :***
I would like when user clicks save button on CRM opportunity form ,aspx page should store the data in external database and opportunity form should also save all the changes on `CRM` form.

***My Efforts :***

Till now I have Iframed aspx page on `CRM` form.I am also submitting the form using OnSave event.
But the only problem is the form gets submitted but by the time it executes the complete code CRM form gets refreshed . End result is that Data on `aspx` page does not get stored in the external database.

What can be the other possible way to achieve this functionality ?

Thanks for taking time to read. Thank you in advance.

Comment: May be submitting the form data Asynchronously works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** The better solution is to do this from an opportunity post event plug-in. This ensures data consistency between CRM and external data (if required). Also you could use WCF or a web service to transmit the data to external DB.

**Option 2:** If you must use javascript you could (1) bind to opportunity form OnSave, (2) Prevent the form from submitting , (3) submit the iframe and (4) wait until it comes back and then (5) do another save to complete the action. This however might cause inconsistencies between CRM and external DB if opportunity save fails.

Here is a pseudo code example

```
function OpportunityOnLoad() {

    IFRAME.OnReadyStateChange = function() {
        // (4) Check success if possible 
        // (5) unbind save event and complete the opportunity save
        Form.RemoveOnSave(OpportunityOnSave)
        Form.Save();
    }

    //OnLoad
    Form.AddOnSave (OpportunityOnSave);
}


function OpportunityOnSave(context) {
   //(1) Save clicked
   //(2) Stop save
   context.PreventDefault();
   //(3) Submit iframe form
   IFRAME.Submit();
}
```

EDIT:
Regarding Q1 : unfortunately not.
Regarding Q2 :

This is a rough translation of the concept above into Javascript and CRM client side API. 
I didn’t test it but it should put you on the right track.

Change the Params to match the iframe id, url etc. 
also since you’re using an aspx you might experience cross domain issue that could be easily overcome if you’re browsing IE and not so easily overcome if you’re using CROME for example.

```
var IFRAME, SaveMode; 
var FORM = Xrm.Page.data.entity;
var UI = Xrm.Page.ui;

var SaveModes = {
   1 : "save", 
   2 : "saveandclose", 
   59: "saveandnew" 
}

var Params = {
   IframeBaseUrl : "",
   IframeId : "IFRAME_test",
   IframeFormId : "form1"
}

function OpportunityOnLoad() {
    var sUrlparams = "?";  //add required params after ?  
    var IframeUrl = Params.IframeBaseUrl + sUrlParams; 

    IFRAME = UI.controls.get(Params.IframeId);
    IFRAME.setSrc(IframeUrl);
    IFRAME.Dom = document.getElementById(Params.IframeId);
    IFRAME.add_readyStateComplete(OnAfterIfameSave);

    FORM.addOnSave(OpportunityOnSave);
}

function OnAfterIfameSave() {
    //SubmitSuccess indicates that the form has reloaded after a  
    //successful submit. You'll need to set this variable inside your iframe.

    if (IFRAME.contentWindow.SubmitSuccess) {
        FORM.removeOnSave(OpportunityOnSave);
        FORM.save(SaveModes[SaveMode]);
    }
}

function OpportunityOnSave(execObj) {
   var evArgs = execObj.getEventArgs();

   evArgs.preventDefault();
   SaveMode = evArgs.getSaveMode();
   IFRAME.contentWindow.document
    .getElementById(Params.IframeFormId)
    .Submit();
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for taking time and answering my question.

I still have few questions about the code you have provided.

Q-1 : Is it possible to access and submit IFrame through CRM Plugin project ? (i.e Post Account Created.)

Q-2 : If Yes then can you provide real code may be only few important pieces like how can I access IFrame and how do I submit ?